# SaltStack: install packages behind proxy

Tags: saltstack

Getting through a Saltstack tutorial and ran into a problem how to install packages on a linux host if it's behind a proxy. For example, I have a file nettools.sls:

```
install_network_packages:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - rsync
      - lftp
      - curl
```

How can I pass env variables like `http_proxy` so to install packages? Thank you.

Comment: did you look at https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.environ.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can for a `pkg.installed` state. What you can do is configure your package manager (APT if Debian/Ubuntu, RPM/YUM if Centos/RedHat...) to know that it must use a HTTP proxy.